# Show Lightbox inside a div container

Tags: tinymce

I need to show the image inside lightbox.Images are inserted by the text editor tinymce.Images are inside a div container without `<a>` tags.How to show images in lightbox that are inside a div container without `<a>` tags wrapping. I did not find any example that is showimg images with `<img>` tag.which lightbox to use that takes `<img>` tag and shows it inisde lightbox

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this may this solve your problem  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_lightbox

Comment: I cannot add onclick event to image tag

Comment: So handle this click event in JavaScript if you don't want to use onclick